AutoResizeColumn not Wide Enough
I'm using App Script to create a new sheet, insert headers, and then am using AutoResizeColumns to resize the columns to the headers length. The issue is it doesn't seem to be resizing the columns to be wide enough. As in, if I double-click on the dividing line between columns it'll still adjust it out more. I tried searching for a function to allow me to manually set the size of columns, or add additional spacing to AutoResizeColumn, but I couldn't find anything. Does anyone know how I might do this, or why it seems AutoResizeColumns doesn't exactly resize the columns enough? 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().moveActiveSheet(0);
    var headers = ["Timestamp", "Email Address", "Referrals QAd", "Referrals Approved", "Waiting for QA", "Waiting for Review", "Referrals in Held", "Referrals in Held Reason"]; 
    newSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, headers.length).setValues([headers]);
    sht = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var headerRow = sht.getRange(1, 1, 1, 8);
    headerRow.setFontWeight('bold');
    headerRow.setHorizontalAlignment('center');
    sht.autoResizeColumns(1, sht.getLastColumn())


It appears to be a bug. It has been fixed before but apparently it has recurred once again based from this closed ticket. You may file this as a new ticket using this link.

You can try this workaround add this to the last line of code headers.forEach((x, i) => { sht.setColumnWidth(i + 1, sht.getColumnWidth(i+1) + 10) })

Sheets Set Column Width
Here is a workaround to the sheet problem you've encountered.

function to allow me to manually set the size of columns, or add additional spacing to AutoResizeColumn

Additional Code:
headers.forEach((x, i) => {
  //You can adjust the second parameter to the width pixel per cell.
  sht.setColumnWidth(i + 1, sht.getColumnWidth(i + 1) + 10)
});

Sample Output Before:

Sample Output After:

Reference:

Class Sheet

